# How to load angular-formly vm.fields object from remotely-generated json?

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-formly

In my application I have dynamic field sets on what is otherwise the same form.  I can load them from the server as javascript includes and that works OK.

However, it would be much better to be able to load them from a separate API.

$.getJSON() provides a good way to load the json but I have not found the right place to do this.  Clearly it needs to be completed before the compile step begins.

I see there is a fieldTransform facility in formly. Could this be used to transform vm.fields from an empty object to whatever comes in from the API?

If so how would I do that?

Thx. Paul

Answer (score 0):

There is [an example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/json-powered) on the website that does exactly what you're asking about. It uses `$timeout` to simulate an async operation to load the field configuration, but you could just as easily use angular's own `$http` to get the json from the server. It hides the form behind an `ng-if` and only shows the form when the fields return (when `ng-if` resolves to true, it compile the template).

Comment: thx @kentcdodds.
The example was very helpful, introducing $q.
So I need to replace getFields() in that example with an $http.get('fields'json').  That produces a callback not a return value so I can't see how I would make getFields() return that.  Thx. Paul

Comment: hello did u get the output by reading a local json file through angular formly

Answer (score 0):

Thx @kent

OK, so we need to replace the getFields() promise with this

```
function getFields() {
  return $http.get('fields-demo.json', {headers:{'Cache-Control':'no-cache'}});
}
```

This returns data.fields so in vm.loadingData we say

```
vm.fields = result[0].data;
```

Seems to work for OK for me.

When testing I noticed that you have to make sure there is nothing wrong with your json such as using a field type you haven't defined.  In that case the resulting error message is not very clear.

Furthermore you need to deal with the situation where the source of the data is unavailable.  I tried this:

```
function getFields() {
  console.log('getting',fields_url);
    return $http.get(fields_url, {headers: {'Cache-Control':'no-cache'}}).
    error(function() {
      alert("can't get fields from server");
      //return new Promise({status:'fields server access error'}); //??
    });
```

.. which does at least throw the alert.  However, I'm not sure how to  replace the promise so as to propagate the error back to the caller.

Paul

Comment: of course this does not handle errors nicely and still return a promise that contains an error message instead of the data when, for example, the service it's calling is not available.